# Need help with refreshing UIView in iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, drawrect, navigationcontroller, iphone

I have a simple drill down navigation app. On the detail view, I am drawing a few 20x20 sized UIImages, depending upon the row selected in the navigation items. These images are drawn as subviews over the detail view when a row is selected.Now when I get to the "detail view" I have set up a couple of buttons, which when pressed, will rearrange the small images. For this I need to clear the previous images and redraw them at different places in the view.  I have a method like: 
[MyView changeImagePositionwithPosnumber:"number selected by buttons"] 
I cannot pass this method when the button is pressed since it draws over the existing images. 
How do I refresh the view to pass this method ? Do I need to implement draw rect for this? 
I do not quite understand drawrect and am not sure how to implement it. 
In short whatever the navigation controller does when you go away from detail view, I want to do, so I can refresh my view and draw new images on it. 
Any help on this is greatly appreciated. I am still a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
UIView *view:
for(UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}

Thanks